# how to pass/name a function as argument

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I have a function which takes another function as an argument:

```cpp
T reduce(T* pBegin, T* pEnd, T(*operate)(T, T))
{
    T temp = *pBegin;
    for (T* p = pBegin + 1; p < pEnd; p++)
        temp = operate(temp, *p);
    return temp;
}
```

This is the way it is used:

```cpp
int vec[] = { 12,14,6,-8 };
cout << reduce<int>(vec, vec + 4,
    [](int x, int y){ return (x > y) ? x : y; }
);
```

Why is the function name `[]`? Is it because of the `vec` array? Could it be something else?

Comment: You are using a lambda, they don't have any name: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: You don't have to pass a lambda - you could pass any function.  A lambda doesn't have a name - it has a list of capture arguments inside the `[]` followed by the parameters.

Comment: I have to admit that is a hard thing to Google without already knowing it's a lambda expression.

Comment: Re: “I have a function” — no, you have a function **template** (although it’s ill-formed).